# In Ubuntu, alt-tabbing to switch window doesn't open it even though window appears in task switcher

Tags: ubuntu, window-management, alt-tab, task-switching

I try using Alt-Tab to switch to another window, and can see the window in Alt-Tab task switcher, but when I select it, it doesn't open. This happens to me for example with the Text Editor and also the File Manager, and has happened multiple times.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. I suggest deleting it and posting in [ubuntu.se]. You should also specify which desktop environment you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find any answer to this and finally figured it out, so I am sharing.

It turns out you can send windows to another workspace by mistake, even if you don't have workspaces enabled.

I solved this and found my missing windows by:

1. enabling workspaces, and then
2. switching to the next workspace, where I found my missing windows and then sending them back to my primary workspace.

1) To enable workspaces, go to:
  **System Settings > Appearance > Behavior**
and click on the *Enable workspaces* checkbox.

2) To switch to the next workspace, use the keyboard shortcut:
   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

Then select the window you've been missing, and send it back to the first workspace if you'd like, with:
   <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>